# How to reference variable in files folder under roles

Tags: ansible

In one of my ansible roles, I have created a variable via the `"defaults/main.yml"` file. I am able to reference this variable just fine in `"tasks/main.yml"` file. However, the variable does not appear to work in `"files/some_file.txt"`

Is this expected ?

Comment: What is the content of the file? How do you reference the file? Make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Files in the directory `files` are not evaluated automatically. One of the options is `template`. See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's expected. tasks/main.yml is being parsed by ansible and will replace variables as you've seen.

Generally files/some_file.txt should contain static files or scripts that should be used with the copy module. As you've discovered it will not be parsed beyond that.

If you want to use variables in a file you should use the `template` module. Create a `templates` directory and copy your files there e.g `template/some_file.txt`. Note that it's common to rename the file with a .j2 extension to indicate that it is a jinja template e.g `some_file.j2`  but this is not required.

```
- name: Create fact
  set_fact:
    my_variable: 123456

- name: Create file from template
  template:
    src: some_file.j2
    dest: "/tmp/some_file.txt"
    mode: 0755
```

some_file.j2 might contain:

```
This file contains this sentence and the number {{ my_variable }}
```

After the template task run /tmp/some_file.txt will looks like:

```
This file contains this sentence and the number 123456
```

Comment: Can I specify the target of the template as a file in the "files" folder ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `template`. For example, the role

```yaml
shell> cat roles/role-17/defaults/main.yml
var1: value1

shell> cat roles/role-17/files/some_file.txt
[{{ var1 }}]

shell> cat roles/role-17/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    msg: task/main.yml [{{ var1 }}]
- debug:
    msg: files/some_file.txt {{ lookup('template', 'files/some_file.txt') }}
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat test-17.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - role-17
```

give

```
    "msg": "task/main.yml [value1]"

    "msg": "files/some_file.txt [value1]\n"
```